# PHP-FPM open_basedir not working with Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

Is there any way to define open_basedir to virtualhost file in my Apache Event MPM? I tried everything and it just does not want to work. Tried `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE open_basedir="/home/user/web/:/usr/share/phppgadmin/";`

Also tried http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sections.php and that is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass PHP configuration values from Apache when using php-fpm. They must be placed in either the PHP ini file, or the php-fpm pool configuration file.